# Pixelandtonic Assets: Set Content-disposition?

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, s3

Long story short: in Chrome, some PDF files stored in our S3 bucket (uploaded via Assets) hang up on download. Chrome just sits there, never downloading the file. (However, right-clicking the link directly seems to work)

Numerous tutorials exist recommending a Content-disposition Meta parameter be set on the file.

Does anyone know if this is something that should occur during the PUT command when the file is added to the s3 bucket?

Is this something that can be set in Assets?

Answer (score 1):

There's no hook for this in Assets, so you'd have to hack the add-on to add it.

Look at line 821 of `sources/s3/source.s3.php` ... right after this line:

```
$headers = array();
```

You can add something like:

```
$ext = strtolower(pathinfo($file_path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
if($ext == 'pdf')
{
    $headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment';
}
```

Of course, this isn't upgrade-safe, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks, Derek. I might look a little bit further into finding a way to do it on the Amazon site. I'd rather not mess with the core module code. I would think this would be a much more prominent issue, as Chrome is so popular and PDFs are a common format; I wonder if I'm just missing something obvious?